MedusaJS - Can't install a Manual Fulfillment plugin or any plugin
I'm working on a Medusa.js eCommerce project and trying to add the medusa-payment-manual plugin to my backend. Here’s my current setup:
I installed the plugin via npm install medusa-payment-manual.
In my medusa-config.ts, I've added it as follows:
import { loadEnv, defineConfig } from '@medusajs/framework/utils'

loadEnv(process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development', process.cwd())

const plugins = [
  {
    resolve: `medusa-payment-manual`,
    options: {
      // Ajoutez les options spécifiques au plugin ici, si nécessaire
    },
  },
]

module.exports = defineConfig({
  projectConfig: {
    databaseUrl: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
    http: {
      storeCors: process.env.STORE_CORS!,
      adminCors: process.env.ADMIN_CORS!,
      authCors: process.env.AUTH_CORS!,
      jwtSecret: process.env.JWT_SECRET || "supersecret",
      cookieSecret: process.env.COOKIE_SECRET || "supersecret",
    }
  },
  plugins
})

However, when I run npm run start, I get this error:
Error: Unable to find the plugin "medusa-payment-manual".
Troubleshooting Steps Taken

Confirmed the plugin is in node_modules/medusa-payment-manual.
Cleared npm cache and reinstalled dependencies.
Try to install another plugin Manual Payment, but got the same issue


If you are using MedusaJS V2, please note that currently, only the Stripe payment plugin is supported, and no other options are available.
